# css3 fade-in-out

Tags: animation, css-transitions, fadein, fade, fadeout

There are lots of css3 fade in/fade out animation out there. Is there something that would do fade-in-out with no trigger (e.g. no hover or click) that runs itself with animation-duration?

Thanks,
B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should comsider [css3 animation framework](http://daneden.me/animate/). There lots of codes for it.

Also consider animation of opacity (from 1 to 0)